# expect.anything() not working with expect.toBe()

Tags: javascript, jestjs

expect.anything() does not work with expect.toBe(), but works with expect.toEqual()

```
test("this will pass", () => {
  expect("red").toEqual(expect.anything());
  expect("red").toBe(expect.anything());
});
```

both tests should pass but the second one fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[toBe](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/matchers.js#L48) compares values using `Object.is` (See [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description)); 
`expect.anything()` returns object of Anything [class](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/asymmetricMatchers.js#L94)

So, in second case you're comparing string with object - that's why it fails.

[toEqual](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/matchers.js#L411) in fact calls [method](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/jasmineUtils.js#L31) that is prepared to work with matcher objects (like instances of `Anything` class) - it calls matcher's `asymmetricMatch` method.

Since in first case `asymmetricMatch` returns `true`, first test passes.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. The code links were really helpful. Appreciate it